# Entity Framework Odd Behaviour

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, associations

I've not been working with EF until this week (v5) and now I'm making a few database changes it's doing some really weird things.

I deleted an NVARCHAR Country field and replaced that with an CountryId int field that is a Foreign Key to the Id column of the Country table

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_Countries]   FOREIGN KEY([CountryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Countries] ([Id])
```

Updating the model in VS2012 is doing some really unexpecting things.  Its reporting an error on the field I removed:

> Error 11010: Association End 'Country' is not mapped.

And I have two virtual fields added to the model which doesn't seem correct:

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country1 { get; set; }
}
```

I've read there is a bug with the designer and manually running "Run Custom Tool" on the .tt files fixes this but it doesn't appear to have worked.

Has anyone seen this or solved it?

Comment: Do you have an existing database or is the database evolving along with the project? If the latter is true, you should consider using EF Code First instead of relying on the .tt stuff: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx or http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19233/Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Comment: It's evolving along with the project at the moment.  This designer seems incredibly clunky and buggy, SQLMetal worked like a charm in comparison!  It's putting me off using EF altogether.

Thanks for the links, I'll go read this now

Comment: Yeah, I've never liked the designer either. It was a relief when Code First become thoroughly supported in EF 4(.1 I think it was). No models and diagrams, just sweeeeeet code :)

Comment: Are you using the database first or model first approach?  That is, do you make the changes in your model then regenerate the database, or do you make the changes in your database then reverse engineer them to the model?

Comment: I'm going from the database to the model and it's frankly an horrific experience ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record I've burned through so much time on Database First I'm ditching it all and writing code instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing I've totally recreated my model from scratch.  Deleted all the files.  After recreating the model from the ground up looking in the Country.cs file scared the life out of me ... if my assumption is correct.  The class ended up looking like this:

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

If my assumption about this is as it appears this looks terrifying from a performance point of view.  From looking at that class it looks like if I retrieved say, the row for the United States it would then also load every profile with US as the country ... or am I going mad?  The designer has fried my brain today ...